# Docker: host grabs ICMP packets (Strongswan IPsec)

Tags: networking, vpn, docker, ipsec, strongswan

These machines are Docker containers with `strongswan` installed running IPsec tunnels.

`routeur1` and `routeur2` have a site-to-site IPsec tunnel, while `pc-nomad` have a IPsec tunnel with `routeur1`. `routeur1` have `pc1` as client in their subnet.

`pc-nomad` reaches `pc1`, [but apparently the host grabs the ICMP packet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwUkG.png) and it doesn't return the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I found was to add a NAT rules in the routers for the packets coming from the 192.16.1.0/24 subnet :

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j MASQUERADE`

But still, it seems weird that the host takes the packet from the other subnet.